# WP migration, can't login to WP admin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, migration

I was in the middle of migrating a local WP site to a live server and came across a problem.

I edited my WP config file and uploaded it along with the rest of the WP files. I also uploaded the mysql database through phpMyAdmin.

Once i tried to test the site i got an error message "The page isn't redirecting properly". I then, mistakenly, logged in to the admin area and in the Settings > General tab I deleted the localhost part of the URL. Now I'm unable to log back in to the WP admin area.

*EDIT*

To clarify, my major problem is that i can no longer log in to the wp admin area because of something I've done. The steps i took to get to this point were:

1. Backed up WP using the BackUpWordpress plugin
2. Edited back up wp-config file with    `define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');` `define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');`
3. Created mySQL database through DreamHost
4. Changed database info in wp-config file
5. Uploaded wp files (not including mySQL backup) to my url using Filezilla
6. Imported mySQL database backup to DreamHost
7. I then checked the site from my browser, an error message said too many redirects occurred
8. From the wp admin area i went to Settings > General and deleted the localhost part of the url that was displayed.
9. I believe it's due to the previous step I'm now unable to access the wp admin area at all.

I need a way of getting back into the admin area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that studiomed.co.uk is permanently redirected (301) to www.studiomed.co.uk and www.studiomed.co.uk is permanently redirected (301) to studiomed.co.uk

Login to your Dreamhost account go to **Domains**->**Manage Domains** and choose one of the three options there are in "**Do you want the www in your URL?**".

After that use an ftp program to download the **.htaccess** file that exists in your root installation of wordpress and open it with your favorite editor. Check if you have any kind of redirection in the .htaccess file.

Comment: I was able to login to my admin area by using the RELOCATE method and you were correct about the redirects. I'm up and running now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can also edit those options within phpMyAdmin. Go to wp_options and locate siteurl and home. Make sure the URL matches your site URL.

Comment: hi Michael, I can only locate site url, i can't see home in my phpMyAdmin

Comment: Follow these directions here for changing your URL via your database: http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL. Also be sure to click on page 2 and so on. There might be multiple pages worth of tables.

Comment: I've found and changed both site url and home values wp_options. Still no change. Would i need to find and change them in another file?

Comment: No, there's likely another issue going on but without more information, it's hard to tell what's wrong. Delete any changes you had made previously perhaps through your functions.php file.

Comment: i've deleted those changes and i still have the same problem. I've edited my original questions to include the steps i made to get to this point, maybe it can help with a solution

Answer (score 1):

You can also edit the site URL in your wp-config.php.

Add these lines somewhere above the /* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */ line.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://my-site.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://my-site.com');
```

This should overwrite your database settings.

Comment: So, do I get this right? Your homepage is loading properly (now), and you just have problems to login the admin area? 
If yes – are there any redirect rules behind the /wp-login.php in your browser's address bar?

Comment: My homepage isn't loading and I'm unable to log in to the admin

Answer (score 0):

Which **version** of WordPress do you use?
Can you list the plugins you are using?

Have you gone through the basic WordPress troubleshooting steps?

- flush any caching plugins you might be running, as well as server
  and/or browser caches.
- deactivate **all plugins** to see if this resolves the problem. If this
  works, re-activate the plugins one by one until you find the
  problematic plugin(s). Sometimes, an apparently inactive plugin can
  still cause problems.
- **If you can't get into your admin dashboard**,
  try resetting the plugins folder by FTP or PhpMyAdmin (read
  http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Troubleshooting#How_to_deactivate_all_plugins_when_not_able_to_access_the_administrative_menus.3F
  if you need help).
- switch to the Twenty Eleven theme (depends on your WordPress version) to rule out any theme-specific problems.
- If you can't log in to change themes, you can remove the theme folders via FTP so the only one is twentyeleven. That will force your site to use it.
- manual upgrade. When all else fails, download a fresh copy of the latest.zip file to your computer, and use that to copy up. You may need to delete the wp-admin and wp-includes folders on your server. Read the Manual Update directions first: http://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress#Manual_Update
- check the Master List to see if you're experiencing a known issue

Login to your wordpress dashboard (wp-admin) and go to **Settings**->**Permalinks**, select **Default** and save changes.

Comment: I'm running wp 3.7. The plugins i have installed are BackUpWordpress, Advanced Custom Fields and Custom Post Types. I'll go over the possible solutions you've suggested

Comment: I suggest to start from "try resetting the plugins folder by FTP".

Comment: i've tried resetting the plugins although I'm pretty sure its not a plugin problem. Ive also gone through all of the solutions on the Changing The Site URL codex and still not able to access the admin area

Comment: I haven't changed the .htaccess file, was I meant to? I'm new to wp development and was following a tutorial for the migration process, it said nothing about changing the file at this point

Comment: @user3195115 Can you provide us the url of your website?

Answer (score 0):

**Update all urls(path) using this querys then check:--**

Use this querys for change all urls(path) for db then check

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://live_ste_path.com', 'http://localhost/local_site_path') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://live_ste_path.com', 'http://localhost/local_site_path');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://live_ste_path.com','http://localhost/local_site_path')`
```

Answer (score -1):

[WSOD RESOLVED]

Since I could not find any solution to my problem by googling around, a crucial tracking info I finally found in WP error logs. So I would recommend to inspect logs before spending to much time looking for a proper answer by google.

After migration from an old web host to a new one, in my multisite environment all sites were working. Also, I was able to administer all subsites - but one! Trying wp-admin login to that site led me to fatal white screen. Without any message or any indication about the reason. And the culprit was corrupted file /public_html/subsite-x/wp-admin/admin.php. I really could not understand how that happened, just might suppose it appeared somehow while transferring files (FTP) from old host to a new one.